# Sabre PCC / iPCC max length & character requirements

Tags: sabre

I can't find official specs on Sabre PCC / iPCC max length & character requirements.

Docs usually mention PCC in commands as `XXXX` placeholder and I saw only 4 character uppercase alphanumeric so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are always 4 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I saw some misleading articles over Internet abut 3 or 5 character but that information isn't directly about Sabre system. That is why I am worried...

Comment: Right - Sabre is always 4. Other systems use different schemes for their Pseudo City Codes (Worldspan uses 3 characters, for example).